# Vectors that form a triangle!

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a problem here.

How can I prove that sum of vectors that form a triangle is equal to 0 $(\vec {AB}+\vec {BC}+\vec {CA}=\vec 0)$ ?

Comment: How do you define vector addition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

from the triangle law : $\vec {AB}+\vec{BC}=\vec{AC}$

$\vec {AC}$ will be resultant vector of addition of other two vectors.

$\vec {AB}+\vec{BC}=\vec{AC}$

$\vec {AB}+\vec{BC}+\vec{CA}=\vec{AC}+\vec{CA}$ (add $\vec{CA}$ on both side)

$\vec {AB}+\vec{BC}+\vec{CA}=\vec{AC}-\vec{AC}$

(because when AC and CA are same in magnitude but they are opposite in direction)

$\vec {AB}+\vec{BC}+\vec{CA}=\vec0$

hence proved

Comment: sorry for drawing mistake this is a triangle there are no break

Answer (score 2):

well, define $A := (a_1,a_2, \dots ,a_n)$, then $B := (b_1,b_2, \dots ,b_n)$ and $C := (c_1,c_2, \dots ,c_n)$.

Then $\overrightarrow{AB}=(b_1-a_1,b_2-a_2, \dots ,b_n-a_n)$ similarly $\overrightarrow{AC}=(c_1-a_1,c_2-a_2, \dots ,c_n-a_n)$ and $\overrightarrow{BC}=(b_1-c_1,b_2-c_2, \dots ,b_n-c_n)$.

let's make $\overrightarrow{AB}+\overrightarrow{BC}= (b_1-a_1 + c_1-b_1,b_2-a_2+c_2-b_2, \dots ,b_n-a_n+c_n-a_n) = \overrightarrow{AC}=-\overrightarrow{CA}$
and hence the result.

NB if you don't know how to work with vectors, then you may want to take a look here [Wiki - vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector). I've worked in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with and affine structure on it.

Answer (score 0):

Vector addition is defined as follows:
$$\vec{PQ}+\vec{QR}:=\vec{PR}$$
So that, $\vec{AB}+\vec{BC}+\vec{CA}=\vec{AC}+\vec{CA}=\vec{AA}={\bf 0}$.