# triangle, vectors, proving an identity.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I'm trying to prove something but unfortunately I can't.

Let $ABC$ be a triangle and $M$ a point in $[AB]$ where $d(A,M)=d(B,M)$.Let also be
$N$ be a point in $[AC]$ where $d(A,N)=d(B,N)$.

Prove that $\overrightarrow{BC}=2\overrightarrow{MN}$.

Thanks!

Comment: your efforts? where do you are struck?

Comment: First, there's a typo. It should read $\overrightarrow{BC}=2\overrightarrow{MN}$. Start by letting $\vec x=\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\vec y=\overrightarrow{AC}$, and use them and only them to get what you want.

Comment: See also [this related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/105084/28900), which will help you prove similarity, and thus the claim.

Answer (score 0):

$1^{st}$ MODE:

prove the [similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_%28geometry%29#Similar_triangles) between the 2 triangles ($ABC$,$AMN$) you have, and then calculate the ratio between the sides

to be more exhaustive, hence you proved the similarity (they have the same angles) the ratio between sides is given you by hypothesis (let's call it $k \in \mathbb{R}$) so $k\overrightarrow{MN}=\overrightarrow{BC}$.

Pay attention of what you use in the numerator/denominator of the fraction to compute $k$.

$2^{nd}$ MODE:

following the advices given you in your previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395462/vectors-that-form-a-triangle) we can conclude that $$\overrightarrow{AM}-\overrightarrow{AN}=\overrightarrow{NM}$$ $$\overrightarrow{AB}-\overrightarrow{AC}=\overrightarrow{CB}$$

by hypothesis $$\overrightarrow{AB}=2\overrightarrow{AM}$$ $$\overrightarrow{AC}=2\overrightarrow{AN}$$ then the proof follows easily (substitution :) )

Comment: I think the OP wants to do a vector proof — as I require in my linear algebra classes — as opposed to a classic Euclidean geometry argument.

Comment: vectorized :) thanks